# Javascript to change input value without overriding value

Tags: javascript, input

I'm looking to change the value of an input **without** setting `element.value`. That is to say edit the value without replacing the entire value in the element.

For example, removing the first character from the input field:

`this.value.substring(1)` returns a value instead of modifying the string directly, so no effect on the value there.

I've tried treating the string like an array, but neither `this.value.shift()` nor `Array.prototype.shift.apply(this.value, [])` work, which isn't too surprising.

---

The ultimate reason here is to change input value without affecting caret position. Yes, I know I can manually set caret position after setting input value, but that creates its own buggy behavior I'm attempting to circumvent altogether.

Again, change value (remove or insert a character at any given position) in a text input:

**Without** setting element.value directly

**Without** setting or modifying caret position

Is this even possible?

Comment: Strings in javascript are immutable, so you can only reassign string properties/variables. Your only solution to this is indeed to set the caret position after rewriting the value property

Comment: P.S. This is exactly why most implementations resort to only modifying the value property after the input loses focus

Comment: @MikaelLennholm sounds like a solid **answer** if you'd like to post it as such...

Comment: You got it! (I'm usually hesitant to post "sorry, not possible" answers)

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I am as well, but as long as it's authoritative (string are immutable is a pretty solid explanation) it's good to have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in Javascript are immutable, so you can only reassign string properties/variables.

In the case of input values, there would also be the logical problem for the browser of knowing where the caret should be placed after a programmatic change (should it remain at the position it was before, should it be moved and in that case where?).

Your only solution to this is indeed to set the caret position after rewriting the `value` property. Though as you mention, such solutions are often brittle and buggy and that's exactly why most implementations resort to only modifying the `value` property **after** the input loses focus.